# MS Access - Totals in Report

Tags: microsoft-access, report

I have constructed a database in Microsoft Access and have a report in which I want to include the number of alerts that relate to certain areas.

If I wanted to include the number of alerts relating to "Drug Alert", how would I go about including this in the report?

The data is stored in a table - let's call it "Alerts" - and I wish to "pull" this data from the table and include it in my report so that I needn't do it by hand/manually.

For example, I am looking to achieve something like this:

```
Total no. of Drug Alerts this quarter: [total will go here (pulled from "Alerts" table)]
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how this is done.  I have set the control source of the report object (in this case, a text box) to the following:

```
=Sum(IIf([Category]="Drug Alert",1,0))
```

I hope that this helps all of you who are (were) experiencing the same problem.